# backwards looping in table, with repeat

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I try to loop backwards in table.

I try it like this:

```
KlantContact.SETFILTER("No.", "<Contact>"."No.");
   FOR i := 0 TO KlantContact.COUNT  DO BEGIN
      IF KlantContact.FINDSET THEN BEGIN REPEAT //  KlantContact.FINDSET  THEN BEGIN REPEAT
        //KlantContact.CALCFIELDS(KlantContact."No.");
          MESSAGE(KlantContact.Name);
      UNTIL  KlantContact.NEXT -1 = 0;
        //MESSAGE(KlantContact.COUNT);
      END;
     END;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the key, set descending order and loop through the table with REPEAT..UNTIL:

```
Record.RESET;
Record.SETCURRENTKEY("Field1","Field2");
Records.ASCENDING(FALSE);
IF Record.FINDSET(FALSE,FALSE) THEN BEGIN
  REPEAT
  // do something
  UNTIL Record.NEXT = 0;
END;
```

If you want to modify the table use the parameters in FINDSET accordingly.

Cheers!